# Platform vs Software Framework

Tags: cuda

CUDA advertises itself as a [parallel computing platform](http://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2012/09/10/what-is-cuda-2/). However, I'm having trouble seeing how it's any different from a software framework (a collection of libraries used for some functionality). I am using CUDA in class and all I'm seeing is that it provides libraries in C for - functions that help in parallel computing on the GPU - which fits my definition of a framework. So tell me, how is a platform like CUDA different from a framework? Thank you.

Comment: I think the platform part comes from also providing the middleware that talks to the underlying hardware, thus abstracting it away from you and allowing you to only code to the CUDA layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA the hardware platform, is the actual GPU and its scheduler ("CUDA architecture"). However CUDA is also a programming language, which is very close to C. To work with the software written in CUDA you also need an API for calling these functions, allocating memory etc. from your host language. So CUDA is a platform, a language and a set of APIs.

If the latter (a set of APIs) matches your definition of a software framework, then the answer is simply yes, as both options are true.